# How can I prevent page from jumping after form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I'm using a Shopify Theme which I've been editing as required. I have chosen to move the newsletter subscription form from the bottom of the page to the top so I can embed it into the hero image. When the user submits the form the page jumps to the bottom (where the form used to be). Below is the website and the code for the form.

www.hoo-gah.co.uk

```
<div class="signup-form">
           {% if settings.footer_signup_action == empty %}
               {% form 'customer' %}
             {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
               <h4>{{ 'layout.signup.post_success' | t }}</h4>
               <script>window.scroll(0,1000000)</script>
             {% else %}
                   <input type="hidden" id="contact_tags" name="contact[tags]" value="prospect,newsletter"/>
                   <span class="input-block">
                     <input type="email" placeholder="{{ 'layout.signup.email' | t }}" class="required" value="" id="mailinglist_email" name="contact[email]" /><input class="compact" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
                   </span>
             {% if form.errors %}
                   {% for field in form.errors %}
                   <p class="error">{{ field | capitalize }} - {{ form.errors.messages[field] }}</p>
                   {% endfor %}
             {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
           {% endform %}
           {% else %}
           <form action="{{ settings.footer_signup_action }}" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank">
            <span class="input-block hero-input">
              <input type="email" class="required email" placeholder="{{ 'layout.signup.email' | t }}" value="" id="mce-EMAIL" required name="EMAIL" /><input class="compact" type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Subscribe" />
            </span>
           </form>
          {% endif %}
</div>
```

I thought that the line window.scroll(0,1000000) would be responsible for this, but even when I delete the line or change the values to (0,0) the screen still jumps upon submit, so I'm wondering if this is being overridden somewhere.

If anyone has any ideas on how to make the page scroll to the top instead of to the bottom, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your JavaScript, but have you tried an `event.preventDefault();` on click?

Comment: I saw this as a solution in a similar post but it was suggested this would prevent the form from being submitted altogether.

Comment: Unless you use JavaScript to submit the form. It's up to you. Can you post all your related JS as well?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't find the relevant JS. As you can tell I'm slightly out of my depth! I think OZ was onto something, but editing the form action value in the settings_data.json file has some unexpected effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `#contact_form` from `action="/contact#contact_form"` in your form element, and life will be beautiful again.

The #contact_form tells the browser to scroll to the form.Removing it will have no other affect.

Just to be clear this is the form to change:

```
<form method="post" action="/contact#contact_form" id="contact_form" class="contact-form" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input type="hidden" value="customer" name="form_type"><input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓">

                       <input type="hidden" id="contact_tags" name="contact[tags]" value="prospect,newsletter">
                       <span class="input-block">
                         <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." class="required" value="" id="mailinglist_email" name="contact[email]"><input class="compact" type="submit" value="Subscribe">
                       </span>


                       <p class="error">Email - can't be blank</p>



                </form>
```

Should be:

```
<form method="post" action="/contact" id="contact_form" class="contact-form" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input type="hidden" value="customer" name="form_type"><input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓">

                       <input type="hidden" id="contact_tags" name="contact[tags]" value="prospect,newsletter">
                       <span class="input-block">
                         <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." class="required" value="" id="mailinglist_email" name="contact[email]"><input class="compact" type="submit" value="Subscribe">
                       </span>


                       <p class="error">Email - can't be blank</p>



                </form>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply! Just wanted to let you know I've seen your response and expect you're right - I'm just having trouble finding this part of the code... the way shopify nests files sometimes makes locating things tricky. I'll be back to mark as answered once I get it working :) Thanks!

Comment: Edit: playing around with inspect element I can see under the Properties tab > input.compact > form > outerHTML - that outerHTML seems to be where action="/contact#contact_form" is inherited from. Not sure how to edit or override outerHTML at the moment though.

Comment: Edit 2: Have since found where to change the code to action="/contact" but this now seems to open up the page in a new window when the form is submitted which is strange behaviour...

Comment: @JackWatson Can I see this ? This is strange, because the # part is not sent to server at all. Only adding target="_blank" will cause this affect

Comment: sure, I've just changed it to "footer_signup_action":="/contact" whereas previously it was in fact blank like this - "footer_signup_action":""

Comment: @JackWatson Why do you have target="_blank" in the form ??? , this was not there before. I actually copy pase it in my answer and it was not there

Comment: it was blank before. If I change it back to being blank (I just did this now), and the user submits the form it takes them to the page https://www.hoo-gah.co.uk/?customer_posted=true#contact_form ... very confusing - I'm not sure where it's getting the #contact_form from.

Comment: Actually - if you look at the code I posted in the original question, I think it might have something to do with the line if settings.footer_signup_action == empty

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I encountered the same issue today. I have to answer because I can't just comment yet. Also, based on O_Z answer :

You should replace this piece of code :

```
 {% form 'customer' %}
```

by this one

```
{% form 'customer', action:'/contact' %}
```

That's the proper way to do it I guess. It is not well (or at all) documented in Shopify, but you can add elements (action, classes, data-type etc.) directly from your html file, just like the above example. In my case, after the form is submitted, the page stays on top by default and no longer scrolls.